# How to compare if the configuration is different for IIS?

Tags: iis-7

Suppose I have IIS running on 2 different computers, I want to know if the 2 IIS configurations are different. How can I compare the configuration settings on different IIS Web Servers?

Answer (score 19):

Compare IIS configuration files located in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` directory.
OR
If you use WebDeploy tool:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:webServer,computername=YourSourceMachine -disableLink:ContentExtension -dest:webServer,computername=YourDestinationMachine -whatif > c:\sync.log
```

In `c:\sync.log` file you will see what would take to synchronize IIS configuration from YourSourceMachine to YourDestinationMachine. Because `-whatif` parameter is provided it will only symulate synchronization process.

Comment: what path is mdeploy.exe usually stored under?

Comment: You need to download mdeploy.exe, it does not come preinstalled.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for it, you can obtain msdeploy.exe from [https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).